# MySQL query: merge result of many rows into 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use MySQL query to merge result of many rows into 1 row by appending next record to the first one until the end of result, is it possible? I do not want to use any other application to process this task, any SQL geeks here?

Comment: Post your current query and what did you try already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
Select 

GROUP_CONCAT(column SEPARATOR ',')
from myTABLE
GROUP BY PKCOlumn
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `SELECT` with `GROUP BY` clause together with some aggregate function.

If you want to concatenate strings into one, appropriate aggregate function is [`group_concat()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).